# Android Studio acting weird when I hover options

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I have a problem (a big one) that makes programming in Android Studio really hard.

Whenever I try to hover on an option it simply shows the UI again behind the mouse.

[Here is an example os the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anb31.png)

So what should I do to solve this thing? I can't use Android Studio meanwhile.

(sorry for my English)

Comment: wrong community, try SuperUser. your question isn't about programming but about using a GUI tool used for programming. but still about using.

Comment: Report issue here http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs

Comment: @nonchip This question is on-topic; questions about tools used for programming are allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks. i will report it, hope it get solved soon